# Tag merger - urllib and urllib2

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

So, I was asking a question today and noticed there were tags for [urllib](/questions/tagged/urllib) and [urllib2](/questions/tagged/urllib2). It makes more since to merge these two into a single [python-urllib](/questions/tagged/python-urllib) considering the reorganization in Python 3.

Comment: What if people are using Python 2?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is `urllib` different enough from `urllib2`? I still think they should at least of the `python-` prefix attached.

Answer (score 7):

Even within the [python2.x](/questions/tagged/python2.x) series, the [urllib](/questions/tagged/urllib) and [urllib2](/questions/tagged/urllib2) modules are significantly different - so certainly aren't synonymous and *should not* be merged. As long as a question is tagged [python3.x](/questions/tagged/python3.x) (or a specific 3.x version - nb: even if it's not - the Python community are quick to identify and appropriately re-tag questions) then the [urllib](/questions/tagged/urllib) tag has enough context to avoid ambiguity.

As to prefixing tag names with `python-` - I'm not 100% sure - I'm personally -0 on it, as we'd also need to consider [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools), [functools](/questions/tagged/functools) and [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess) etc... (although I don't think [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess) really should be Python specific (and there's also a [python-subprocess-module](/questions/tagged/python-subprocess-module) *sighs*)...

Comment: Well, what I am concerned about is where to put questions relating to Python 3 `urllib`.

Comment: @Nathan2055 The way the tags are set up at the moment, you can get across your intent by using the `urllib` tag and either the `python3.x` (or more specific) tag. Perhaps not the best of approaches, but until we can agree on a way the tagging could be improved (some of the Wiki entries definitely need updating), then it's the best we've got...

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty major changes in what the classes are called between urllib and urllib2, at least when I was mucking with them. `urllib.urlopen` becomes `urllib.request.urlopen`, for example. Keeping them separate makes sense to me because the code would be different.